# How to disable delete option for particular value in ChipInput(material-ui-chip-input)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using [chip input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-chip-input) field for entering emails. I want to disable delete functionality for particular values. Let's say, I am populating input field with remote data and also I am giving functionality to add new chips but I want to disable delete option for values which are being fetched(previous values). I have gone through the documentation, I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I have used "material ui chip input" it has chipRenderer function. It is callback function which will render the chip as per provided values.

Sample code:

```
 chipRenderer={({value}, key) => (
            <Chip
              key={key}
              label={value}
              deleteIcon={
              <CancelIcon/>}
              onDelete={adminEmails.length > 0 && adminEmails.includes(value) ? undefined : () => {
                  let oldValues = [...formik.values.super_admin_email];
                  let index = key
                  if (index > -1) {
                    oldValues.splice(index, 1);
                    formik.setFieldValue("super_admin_email", oldValues);
                  }
                }
              }
            >
            </Chip>
              )}
```

Inside chipRenderer first I checked if the given email is old email or newly entered email. If it is old email then I removed delete button from chip and if it is newly entered email then delete button is rendered.

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-river-hfs41?file=/src/App.js:1275-1534)

Comment: Your snippet has syntax errors, please fix them and update your answer.

Comment: Actually this is sample callback function, If you want I can create an example in code sandbox

Comment: That would be helpful for the users reading this answer for trying to interpret it, please only use code sandboxes when required otherwise there are code boxes that are accessable via ```language   ...```

Comment: Thanks! Make sure to remove the snippet from answer and add it to a code block

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
  <Chip label="Disabled" disabled={true} />
```